# Why is "Length" added as an extra column in the DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of string (as I have only one column to display.

```
<DataGrid CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" Margin="10,65,20,67"  ItemsSource="{Binding ExpressionCollection}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Expressions" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This is my bound collection.

```
ObservableCollection<string> expressionCollection;
  public ObservableCollection<string> ExpressionCollection
  {
     get { return expressionCollection; }
     set { expressionCollection = value; }
  }

  public ExpressionEditor()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     LoadExpressions();
     this.DataContext = this;
  }

  void LoadExpressions()
  {
     ExpressionCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
     ExpressionCollection.Add("First");
     ExpressionCollection.Add("Second");
  }
```

The Grid properly displays the collection but there is an extra column added in the end called "Length" and its values are the length of the characters in the expression column.  Why is this added and how do I remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"></DataGrid>
```

and then generate only the columns you want.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. This solved it. But do you know why did it got added?

Comment: Because Length is a public property, and when AutogenerateColumns is set to True, all of the object's properties are being auto-checked and added as columns.